# Programmatically Align Android Elements

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I was programatically creating Android view by using database values. but I don't know how to align the elements. I was creating LinearLayout but it is not Aligning properly.
My actual output is

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

My code

```
lView = new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);
// lView.setPadding(0,150,0,0);
lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams l2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
l2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

GradientDrawable gd3 = new GradientDrawable();
gd3.setCornerRadius(30);
gd3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
gd3.setStroke(0, 0xFF000000);
et1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
et1.setHint("Select Date");
et1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd3);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lView.addView(et1);

GradientDrawable gd4 = new GradientDrawable();
gd4.setCornerRadius(30);
gd4.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5CB85C"));
gd4.setStroke(3, 0xFFFFFFFF);
 Intime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
Intime.setHint("Select In Time");
Intime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Intime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Intime.setTextSize(20);
Intime.setHeight(150);
Intime.setWidth(600);
Intime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
Intime.setLayoutParams(l2);
Intime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lView.addView(Intime);

Outtime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
Outtime.setHint("Select Out Time");
Outtime.setTextSize(20);
Outtime.setHeight(150);
Outtime.setWidth(600);
Outtime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
Outtime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Outtime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Outtime.setLayoutParams(l2);
Outtime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lView.addView(Outtime);
```

Comment: You should either use a RelativeLayout, or a nested LinearLayout. If you use nested LinearLayouts, the top layout must be Vertically oriented, and the inner one with Horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lView = new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);
// lView.setPadding(0,150,0,0);
lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
LinearLayout.LayoutParams l2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
l2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

GradientDrawable gd3 = new GradientDrawable();
gd3.setCornerRadius(30);
gd3.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003366"));
gd3.setStroke(0, 0xFF000000);
et1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
et1.setHint("Select Date");
et1.setBackgroundDrawable(gd3);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lView.addView(et1);

GradientDrawable gd4 = new GradientDrawable();
gd4.setCornerRadius(30);
gd4.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5CB85C"));
gd4.setStroke(3, 0xFFFFFFFF);
Intime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
Intime.setHint("Select In Time");
Intime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Intime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Intime.setTextSize(20);
Intime.setHeight(150);
Intime.setWidth(600);
Intime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
Intime.setLayoutParams(l2);
Intime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);

// lView.addView(Intime);

Outtime = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
Outtime.setHint("Select Out Time");
Outtime.setTextSize(20);
Outtime.setHeight(150);
Outtime.setWidth(600);
Outtime.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
Outtime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Outtime.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
Outtime.setLayoutParams(l2);
Outtime.setBackgroundDrawable(gd4);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
// lView.addView(Outtime);
    
LinearLayout lHorizontalView=new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams l3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
l3.gravity=Gravity.CENTER; 

lHorizontalView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lHorizontalView.setLayoutParams(l3);
lHorizontalView.addView(Intime);
lHorizontalView.addView(Outtime);

lView.addView(lHorizontalView);
```

Comment: Hi.it is aligned in left and it is differing based on the screen size.is there is any solution?

Comment: You can specify the weight property in LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: could you share your output?

Comment: buddy i got. i just changed  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

You must do alignment in xml Sample this code output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kln1g.png

```
 <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am creating elements programatically. i am not using xml file. i can't use xml because page is dynamic.